# Microsoft Web API file upload to Post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to upload an image as a HttpPost to a method.

I tried the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Image(int id)
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count == 1) //do something
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

Then i use postman and added a image as a binary to the body.

However `httpRequest.Files.Count` is 0.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this above code.

Try in the google chrome rest client.. easy to test
i hope that may help you

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Image(int id)
{ 
    string filepath = @"e:\testing\file";
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(filepath);
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
        foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in streamProvider.FileData)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
        }
        string fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
        {
            fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
        }
        if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        }
        File.Move(fileData.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(filepath, fileName));
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

For More details check this [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)

Comment: I set Content-type to multipart/related, but it still wont pass the if-statement?

Comment: Content type should be "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  "see the [attached image reference](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3jfv.png) "

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that your Content-Type is multipart/form-data when you do the post (and application/octet-stream in the data part) as well as proper boundaries. It will also help if you add headers/body of your request to the question.

This one works for me:

```
Header:
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrhNuQUPgZKD8RxKq

Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundaryrhNuQUPgZKD8RxKq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="filename.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryrhNuQUPgZKD8RxKq--
```